# tables = pd.read_html(html) ValueError: No tables found

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to read the data table on this website: [calgary_no_southland_solar](https://geosaurus.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=adaead8cb3174ac6a89f0c14ae70aadd&view=list&sortOrder=desc&sortField=defaultFSOrder#data)
via the following code on jupyter notebook,

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://geosaurus.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=adaead8cb3174ac6a89f0c14ae70aadd&view=list&sortOrder=desc&sortField=defaultFSOrder#data")
html = driver.page_source
tables = pd.read_html(html)
data = tables
print(data)
```

However `ValueError: No tables found` keeps poping up to me.

Comment: You may be having a race condition where the `html = driver.page_source` runs before the Javascript on that page has finished loading the table.

Comment: Hi Nick, Then in this case, I have to remove the line html = driver.page_source ? Thanks